# WatchKit: How to bring the GLANCE INTERFACE onto the watch display?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I have been learning the new `WATCHKIT` framework since last few days. Everything seems quite good stuff from Apple documentation.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TheGlanceController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH16-SW1)

But, I am not clear how does the `GLANCE INTERFACE` comes to foreground? Does watchkit handle that or we need to call explicitly? If watchkit handles that, then when exactly it gets called?

Any help will be greatly helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- iWatch user can enable Glances which he wants to see from default Watch app of iOS device. He can choose from Apps which supports Glance view.
- To see these glances, you simply swipe up from your watch face and then swipe left-right to see different Glances. This is mentioned here, https://www.apple.com/uk/watch/technology/ (Search for 'Glance').